# Set value of textbox on form to a query value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

In Access 2013 64-bit, I have a form for a table with a foreign key to another table which stores the lookup value as an int. On this particular form I'd like to display the lookup as a string value, a particular field from the foreign key relationship.

How do I set the control source to display the value?

E.g. I'd like the query to be:
    SELECT car.[title] FROM cars where cars.[id] = car_id

where car_id is the field with the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DLookup` in the `ControlSource`:

```
=DLookup("Title","Cars","id=" & [car_id] & "")
```

Comment: It's an answer but it's incredibly slow, so I found an alternative workflow.